# How do use methods for the elements of a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

How do use methods for the elements of a 2d array?

I have a class `board`, and initialized a 2d array with type `cell`. Essentially, I want to use the cell elements, and use the methods from that class. 
However, I am unsure how to implement that, because I get an error when I try

```
board[1][1].cellmethod()
```

CODE for BOARD:

```
public class Board {
    private int col = 1, row= 1;
    private cell[][] board;
    private RandomNumberGenerator rand = new RandomNumberGenerator();


    public Board(){
        board = new cell[col][row];
    //Initialize board with cells
        for (int r = 0 ; r<=row; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c<= col; c++){
                board[c][r] = new cell(rand.getRandIntBetween(1,6), translateOffsetToPixel(c,r).getX(), translateOffsetToPixel(c,r).getY());
            }
        }
    }
```

CELL CLASS

```
public class cell {
    //which shape the cell will consist
    private int shape;

    //offset of where the cell is located by cell number -> need to translate the given coordinates to pixel
    private int x, y;

    private int SHAPE_WIDTH = 50;   //Width of each shape (pixels)
    private int SHAPE_HEIGHT = 50;  //Height of each shape (pixels)

    private Rect rect;
    private boolean visible;

    public cell(int shape, int x, int y){
        this.shape = shape;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        rect = new Rect( x, y, x + SHAPE_WIDTH, y + SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        visible = false;
    }

    public int getX() {return x;}
    public int getY() {return y;}
    public int getShape() {return shape;}



}
```

WHERE I CALL the BOARD OBJECT

```
public class PlayState extends State{
    private Board board;


    @Override
    public void init() {
        board = new Board();

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Painter g) {
        for(int r = 0; r<=board.getRow(); r++){
            for(int c = 0; c<=board.getCol(); c++){
                board[0][0].  // ERROR, can't implement any cell methods
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `cell` here? Is it a class? If it is then you can add a method `cellMethod` in that class which can be used like you need.

Comment: Yes, cell is another class I created.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you also add the `cell` class in your question?

Comment: you should get out of bounds exception, because you are using <= in your loop, so it tries to access one extra row and col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `board` array is of size one (row and column).

```
private int col = 1, row= 1;
```

So, your `board` has only one element available at `board[0][0]`, the first row and first column. Accessing `board[1][1]` hence throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Remember that an `array` index can have a maximum value of `array.length - 1` only.

---

In your actual implementation

```
board = new Board();
```

`board` is not an array; it's a `Board` object. So, obviously you can't access it with indices `[][]`. You need to expose the underlying `board[][]` through a getter method.

```
public cell[][] getBoard() {
    return board;
}
```

Then you can use the getter in your `render()` method as

```
@Override
public void render(Painter g) {
    cell[][] boardArr = board.getBoard();
    for(int r = 0; r<=board.getRow(); r++){
        for(int c = 0; c<=board.getCol(); c++){
            boardArr[r][c].cellMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that however my board object still won't allow me to call any of the cell methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
board.board[0][0].cellMethod();
```

while first `board` is an instance of `Board` class, `board.board` refers to the two dimensional array.

I have used `board.board` but you can use a `getter` method to access it if you need to keep it private.

Answer (score 0):

With an array size of 1x1, you can only store one element, at [0][0]. I've changed the array size for you in your code, try this code and see if this works.

CODE for BOARD:

```
public class Board 
{
    private int col = 50, row= 50;
    private cell[][] board;
    private RandomNumberGenerator rand = new RandomNumberGenerator();


    public Board()
    {
        board = new cell[col][row];
    //Initialize board with cells
        for (int r = 0 ; r<=row; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c<= col; c++)
            {
                board[c][r] = new cell(rand.getRandIntBetween(1,6), translateOffsetToPixel(c,r).getX(), translateOffsetToPixel(c,r).getY());
            }
        }
    }
```

*Just a quick tip*

Also, I've found that it makes the readability of code easier if the brackets are placed on the next line after the function for a more aligned look. Like this (and I've also fixed your code accordingly):

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    //code...
}
```